# $E(X|\mathcal G) = EX$ when $X$ and $\mathcal G$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory

> **Problem.** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space, $X\in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ and $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal A$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. If $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal G$ are independent (w.r.t. $P$), then $$E(X|\mathcal G) = EX \quad \text{almost surely}.$$

It suffices to prove that $EX$ is a "version" of the conditional expectation $E(X|\mathcal G)$, in other words, $$\int_A EX dP = \int_A X dP \quad (A\in \mathcal G).$$

The LHS is equal to $EX\cdot P(A)$ but how do we use independence to prove that this coincides with the RHS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_A XdP=\int_{\Omega}X\mathbf{1}_AdP=E[X\mathbf{1_A}]$.

$X$ and $\mathbf{1_A}$ are independent so $E[X\mathbf{1_A}]=E(X)E(\mathbf{1_A})=E(X)P(A)$